# function getElementOfArrayProperty() working but can't pass test

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on the following practice problem but I keep getting an error.

**Question:**
Write a function called "getElementOfArrayProperty".

Given an object, a key, and a numerical index, "getElementOfArrayProperty" returns the value of the element at the given index of the array located within the given object at the given key.

Notes:
* If the array is empty, it should return undefined.
* If the given index is out of range of the array located at the given key, it should return undefined.
* If the property at the given key is not an array, it should return undefined.
* If there is no property at the key, it should return undefined.

```
function getElementOfArrayProperty(obj, key, index) {
  var element = '';
  if (!obj[key] || !obj[key][index] || Array.isArray(obj[key]) === false) {
    return undefined;
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < obj[key].length; i ++) {
      element = obj[key][index];
    }
  }
  return element;
}

var obj = {
 key: ['Jamil', 'Albrey', 'jones', 'justin']
};

getElementOfArrayProperty(obj, 'key', 3);
```

My code returns the correct index value but I keep getting the following error:

*should_return_the_element_at_the_index_of_the_array_at_the_key_of_the_passed_in_object
should return the element at the index of the array at the key of the passed in object*

*Expected undefined to be 0.*

Can anyone see what's going on?

Comment: Why are you using a loop? The "Expected undefined to be 0." implies a test with some other input data that you don't show. I don't suppose you have access to the input that failed?

Comment: you assign the same value to `element` in a loop - that's not your issue, but it is stupid code

Comment: clearly this is in some testing environment, a fact you have failed to mention or describe at all - because `should_return_the_element_at_the_index_of_the_array_at_the_key_of_the_passed_in_object` is specific to your environment

Comment: -_- I am a doofus. Indeed, no loop is needed. Yes this is a testing environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is this code is the issue `!obj[key][index]`. From what i can see, it is expecting `0`. The offending code will treat a value of `0` as `false` and then cause it to return `undefined`.

Change that code to explicitly check for `null` and `undefined` values

```
obj[key][index] == null
```

Comment: Appreciate the help. Figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is on this line:

```
if (!obj[key] || !obj[key][index] || Array.isArray(obj[key]) === false)
```

...specifically the `!obj[key][index]` part.

You aren't testing *just* for undefined elements there, you're also testing for defined elements with falsely values such as empty strings, `null`, or the number `0`.

That's why the test error says *"Expected undefined to be 0."*. Your code misidentified the `0` as an undefined value.

I think you can simplify the function like this:

```js
function getElementOfArrayProperty(obj, key, index) {
  return !Array.isArray(obj[key]) ? undefined : obj[key][index];
}

console.log( getElementOfArrayProperty({ key: ['Jamil', 'Albrey', 'jones', 'justin'] }, 'key', 3) );
console.log( getElementOfArrayProperty({ key: 'not an array' }, 'key', 3) );
console.log( getElementOfArrayProperty({ key: [0, 0, 0, 0] }, 'key', 3) );
console.log( getElementOfArrayProperty({ key: ['outofbounds'] }, 'key', 3) );
```

Once you know that `obj[key]` actually is an array, which you can test directly without first testing whether `obj[key]` is defined, you can just return `obj[key][index]` because if the array is empty or `index` is otherwise out of range it will evaluate to `undefined`.

Comment: Appreciate the help. Figured it out!

Comment: You're welcome. I just edited my answer to provide a rather shorter implementation.

Comment: Yeah, I looked back on the original code and realized how unnecessary  a lot of it was!